# Add header to all responses after processing but before sending to client

Tags: node.js, express

I have two endpoints in a node js app:

```
app.get('search', myGetController);
app.post('add', myPostController);
```

For simplicity, let's assume both services have only the following code:

```
exports.myGetController = function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).json({ error: "not found" });
};
```

I want to have a middleware that is executed after the processing of the controllers, but before they are sent to the browser, so I can add a header based on the body of the response.

```
// process all responses to add ed25519
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('CharCount', [How To get Body content]);
    next();
});
```

I have two questions:

First of all, I would like to have all my controllers pass by that middleware after processing.

Second, I would like to access the body content so I can generate a header based on its content.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the suggested answer someone posted, and it is not working, or I am missing something.

This is what I have (before setting up my routes):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const oldResJson = res.json;

    res.json = function(body) {
        res.setHeader('myToken', generateHeaderBasedOnBody(oldResJson));
        oldResJson.call(res, body);
    }

    next();
});
```

The response that is being passed to my method is an empty string, even though the response sent by the service is not empty. Am I doing this in the wrong place, or what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express middleware before response is carried out to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885425/express-middleware-before-response-is-carried-out-to-client)

Comment: @stdob-- I tried that out but apparently response is empty when the middleware is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for this issue would be to override the `res.json` function like so:

```
// process all responses to add ed25519
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const oldResJson = res.json;

    res.json = function(body) {
        res.setHeader('CharCount', /* Use body here */);
        oldResJson.call(res, body);
    }

    next();
});
```

By doing this, you don't even need to change your controllers.

Comment: I want all my controllers to have this, this is not a solution as I would have to replicate the code in all of them. I would like a centralized middleware to post process all responses and not one by one.

Comment: My answer doesn't relate to controllers. It's a middleware that you have to place for every controllers you want to set the header for.

Comment: I believe your answer was different when I placed the comment. Nonetheless, I have tried your answer, which is similar to the suggested answer, but I could not get this to work. This is executed before the controller is executed, and the response is empty when I try to process it. Have a look at my updated post.

Comment: I see in your updated question that you are doing `generateHeaderBasedOnBody(oldResJson)` but `oldResJson` is a function. You should use `body` instead since it's the json you pass to `res.json` in your controller. `generateHeaderBasedOnBody(body)`